# 80s (maybe 90s) movie with kids feeding aliens butter

Tags: story-identification

Looking for the name of a movie from the 80s or 90s where some kids steal (rescue?) an alien from some other kids and try to feed it butter on a stick.

Comment: There isn't much information for the community to work with.  Is there anything more you can remember, where you saw the movie, did you recognise any of the cast?  Have a look at the guide to see if there is anything to jog your memory further - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This actually sounds familiar

Answer (score -1):

This is an old one but in case someone else want the answer, the movie is Beer money.

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0259882/

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Two things; first, it's always better to provide more information than just a link, in case something happens to the link.  Second, there isn't any (obvious) information at the link that identifies any of the (few) details in the question.  Oh, and since the movie is from 2001, and doesn't features 1 group (not 2) of young adults (not kids), it really doesn't sound like it matches very well at all.